# Type cast void*(*)(void*) to void(*)(void)

Tags: c, multithreading, casting, pthreads

As a part of an assignment, I am trying to create a user level thread library like pthreads.

For handling the context switching between the threads, I am using 'swapcontext' function. Before using it I have to make a context using 'makecontext' function. 'makecontext' expects a function pointer with return type `void` and argument type `(void)`.

Whereas, the thread function has to be of the type `void* thread_func (void*)`

Is there a way to do a typecasting? Or is there some other way to do context switching at the user level?

Comment: isn't that `void*(*)(void*)` to `void(*)(void)` cast you are looking for?

Comment: @Chunk-e-Yamani I've now edited the question to correctly state the cast in the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is illegal to invoke a function with an incompatible prototype by casting the address of the function to a different prototype and invoking it through the resulting pointer:

```
void *my_callback(void *arg) { ... }

void (*broken)(void *) = (void (*)(void *)) my_callback;
broken(some_arg);   // incorrect, my_callback returns a `void *`
```

What you can do is pass to `makecontext` your own callback which will call `thread_func` and ignore its return value. A small function that only serves to call another function is sometimes called a [*trampoline*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computing%29).

```
/* return type is compatible with the prototype of the callback received
   by makecontext; simply calls the real callback */
static void trampoline(int cb, int arg)
{
  void *(*real_cb)(void *) = (void *(*)(void *)) cb;
  void *real_arg = arg;
  real_cb(real_arg);
}

int my_pthread_create(void *(*cb)(void *), void *arg)
{
  ucontext_t *ucp;
  ...
  /* For brevity treating `void *` as the same size as `int` -
     DO NOT USE AS-IS.
     makecontext exposes an annoyingly inconvenient API that only
     accepts int arguments; correct code would deconstruct each
     pointer into two ints (on architectures where pointer is
     larger than int) and reconstruct them in the trampoline. */
  makecontext(ucp, trampoline, 2, (int) cb, (int) arg);
  ...
}
```

For bonus points, you can modify the trampoline to store the `void *` value returned by the callback function on the stack and have your equivalent of `pthread_join()` retrieve it.

Comment: To be precise, casting is totally fine.  However, *calling* a function through the wrong pointer type is undefined behaviour.

Comment: In C, `void (*)()` isn't a function with no arguments - it's an old-style function with a fixed but unspecified number of arguments that does not provide a prototype.  So there's no need for `void (*)()` to be cast in order to call it with an argument.

Comment: @caf You're right; I thought this was removed in C99, but it has merely been *deprecated*. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In principle, you can always cast any type of pointer to any other kind of pointer, but for function pointers, I would **strongly suggest against**.

Your `thread_func` will expect an argument on the stack which will not be provided if invoked after your miscast. Even worse, `thread_func` will write a return value somewhere where it shouldn't, thus corrupting your stack.

A solution would be to wrap the invocation in its own function of appropriate type.

Comment: +1 for the explanation about the stack that user4815162342 ellipsed

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast a function pointer just like a variable.  The syntax is more awkward, but it's certainly possible (whether it's a good idea is another discussion entirely).

In this case, though, it's probably not what you want to do.  From the [man page for `swapcontext`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/swapcontext):

> Before invoking makecontext(), the caller must allocate a new stack
>   for this context and assign its address to ucp->uc_stack,

Your thread function takes an argument.  Pass that argument to the new context via the stack you created.  The function that you pass to `makecontext()` can be a wrapper function that retrieves the value from the stack and passes it to the thread function as an argument.  A typecast alone wouldn't provide a method for getting the data in the argument down to the function in the new context.